# How to declare VARCHAR variables in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to declare a `VARCHAR` variable in MSSQL that can hold this

```
set @RaiseErrorMessage = 
              ('ErrorNumber='+(cast((select ERROR_NUMBER()) as varchar(100)))+
              ,ErrorSeverity='+ (cast((select ERROR_SEVERITY()) as varchar(100)))+
             ',ErrorState='+(cast((select ERROR_STATE()) as varchar(100)))+                                                             
                ',ErrorLine='+(cast((select ERROR_LINE()) as varchar(100)))+
                ,ErrorMessage='+(cast((select ERROR_MESSAGE()) as varchar(100))))
```

How should the declaration look for an variable like this?
I tried

```
 declare @RaiseErrorMessage  varchar
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll need to declare the length of the variable:

```
DECLARE @RaiseErrorMessage VARCHAR(500)
SET @RaiseErrorMessage=' ...... '
```

Comment: To add to this, if you're using SQL Server 2008 and above, this can all be set in one line, if desired: `DECLARE @RaiseErrorMessage VARCHAR(500) = 'ErrorNumber=[...]'`